# Java useDelimiter and nextLine

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to create a program that separate a string input (windows pathway) by using the delimiter. However my programme seems so ignore the delimiter.

The result I am expecting:

```
Skriv in sökvägen: C://Windows/System/

C

Windows

System
```

The result I am getting:

```
Skriv in sökvägen: C://Windows/System/

C://Windows/System/
```

What am I missing in the below code?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Sokvagen 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 

   {

      //String representing pathway
      String sokvag;

      //Creating scanner object for reading from input stream 
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Set delimiter to ':' or '/' or whitespace
      userInput.useDelimiter("[:/\\s]+"); 

      // Instructions to the user to type a windows patway ex: C://Windows/System/
      System.out.print("Skriv in sökvägen: ");

      //Input
      sokvag = userInput.nextLine();

      //Print the result
      System.out.println(sokvag);

      userInput.close();  
   }   
}
```

Comment: Documentation - `nextLine()`: "Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any **line separator** at the end."; `next()`: "Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the **delimiter pattern**."

Comment: consider checking the `Path` (and `Paths`) class....

Comment: When using next () i get 4 instead  
C
C
C
C

Comment: I get `"C"`, `"Windows"` and `"System"`  https://ideone.com/Q8n2jW (obviously better done using a loop, see [Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239530/85421)) ((also no idea why `\s`, aka whitespace as delimiter))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuered out that I should have used 3 strings and use next and everything worked just fine.

```
  //String representing pathway
  String sokvag1, sokvag2, sokvag3;

  //Creating scanner object for reading from input stream 
  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

  // Set delimiter to ':' or '/' or whitespace
  userInput.useDelimiter("[:/\\s]+"); 

  // Instructions to the user to type a windows patway ex: C://Windows/System/
  System.out.print("Skriv in sökvägen: ");

  //Input
  sokvag1 = userInput.next();
  sokvag2 = userInput.next();
  sokvag2 = userInput.next();

  //Print the result
  System.out.println(sokvag1);
  System.out.println(sokvag2);
  System.out.println(sokvag3);

  userInput.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`userInput.nextLine()` always returns the whole line in one piece, while `userInput.next()` returns a token using your delimiter. But then you need to read the input in a loop token by token until ...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String sokvag;

        //Creating scanner object for reading from input stream
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Set delimiter to ':' or '/' or whitespace
        userInput.useDelimiter("[:/\\s]+");

        // Instructions to the user to type a windows patway ex: C://Windows/System/
        System.out.print("Skriv in sökvägen: ");

        do
        {
            //Input
            sokvag = userInput.next();

            //Print the result
            System.out.println(sokvag);
        }
        while (????);

        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is, you do not know when the user entered the last token (the last part of pathway).

So better keep reading the whole input as one line and then split it into parts. For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String sokvag;

        //Creating scanner object for reading from input stream
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Instructions to the user to type a windows patway ex: C://Windows/System/
        System.out.print("Skriv in sökvägen: ");

        //Input
        sokvag = userInput.nextLine();
        String[] parts = sokvag.split("[:/\\s]+");

        //Print the result
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

Of course you can also iterate over the parts-array to output the content line by line.